# Python/Matplotlib: controlling the aspect ratio in gridspec

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to control the aspect ratio of 4 x 1 grid using GridSpec.  I want very wide plots in the horizontal direction, and compact in the vertical direction, but I can't change the aspect ratio predictably (see first pic).  All three settings of the 'height_ratios' below are giving me the same aspect ratio (see second pic below):

One:

```
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(4, 1, width_ratios=[1], height_ratios=[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1])
gs.update(wspace = 0, hspace = 0)

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs[2])
ax4 = plt.subplot(gs[3])

plt.show()
```

Two:

```
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(4, 1, width_ratios=[1], height_ratios=[1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Three:

```
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(4, 1, width_ratios=[1], height_ratios=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
```

I was able to get elongated plots, like I want, by doing this:

```
ax1.set_aspect(0.1)
ax2.set_aspect(0.1)
ax3.set_aspect(0.1)
ax4.set_aspect(0.1)
```

But this adds space between the subplots, which I don't want, and I removed using hspace = 0.  How do I control the aspect ratio without adding space between the subplots?

This is what I want, but I can't seem to get it again and I'm not sure why:

[image]

Instead, all I get is this:

[image]

This is what I get using ax.set_aspect(0.1), which has the correct aspect ratio, but it introduces space between the plots, which I don't want:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the figure size so you'll get the aspect ratio you want, which is controlled through the `figsize` parameter of `plt.figure`. It's not clear that you actually need `GridSpec` in this example; I would do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, axes = plt.subplots(4, 1, figsize=(10, 4))
f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
```

[image]

If you do need to use `GridSpec` for a more complicated layout, you can make the figure with `plt.figure` and then pass the grid slices to the `add_subplot` method of the object that is returned.

Comment: "You need to set the figure size so you'll get the aspect ratio you want" - This isn't necessarily true. You can pass a `subplot_kw` dict into `plt.subplots`.  For example, `f, axes = plt.subplots(4, 1, subplot_kw={'aspect':0.1})`.

Comment: I think that's confusing the `aspect` property that controls the aspect ratio of the *units* with the aspect ratio of the *plot* itself.

Comment: After inspection, I think you are correct.  My mistake. +1

Comment: Thanks!  Setting the figsize worked.  I had a misunderstanding of the width_ratios and height_ratios parameters in GridSpec.  I guess they are setting the aspect ratio of the subplots relative to one another, not the aspect ratio of the plot as a whole.

Comment: What if hspace isn't zero?